# xinetd cannot nmap echo server remotely

Tags: tcp, echo, xinetd

I've configured xinetd and I want to access echo service remotely. The point is, when y do:

```
nmap localhost
```

it appears

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
 7/tcp    open  echo
```

But when i make

> nmap [remote IP]

it doesn't appears

```
> PORT     STATE    SERVICE

21/tcp   open     ftp
23/tcp   open     telnet
80/tcp   open     http
```

and I don't know why

Here is the /etc/xinetd.d/echo

```
> service echo
{
        disable         = no
        type            = INTERNAL
        id              = echo-stream
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        user            = root
        wait            = no
}
```

And here is the /etc/xinetd.conf

```
# Simple configuration file for xinetd

#
# Some defaults, and include /etc/xinetd.d/

defaults {

# Please note that you need a log_type line to be able to use log_on_success
# and log_on_failure. The default is the following :
# log_type = SYSLOG daemon info

}

includedir /etc/xinetd.d
```

Thanks by the way! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error: It was that I've been using the wrong IP.
Thank anyone